# How to create a "3d shaded" button in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, graphics, button, android-layout

I've been looking for a way to create a 3d-shaded button in Android. That is, a standard button with no rounded corners so it is square, and some shading close to the edges so that each border is a different color.

I'd love to be able to set different stroke colors for each side but that doesn't seem possible.

How can I draw a different border color on each side (the border may be shaded with a gradient) and still support different button states?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree it is not possible to achieve using xml stroke approach.

Two possible approaches I see now:

- create different bitmaps for each of states using some specialized software (e.g. Photoshop). This way you can create button visual appearence as you like, but you need to design bitmaps externally. It also uses xml format to specify drawable for each state.
- customize button (by extending it) and draw your button layout using available android.graphics classes. This way is very flexible as you can achieve a number of effects (color gradient, different button shapes, control transparency, emboss ... ) by drawing on the Canvas.